# Error on Sort in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with one sheet. The plan is to add more than one sheet and then apply the same macro across each sheet. I am trying to teach myself VBA and I am taking it one step at a time. 
I have a workbook with one sheet and I want to sort the A column before applying other functions but I keep getting a Compile Error and a Syntax Error. Not sure why. Please help.

```
Public Sub AtRisk()
    ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rowRange As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long


    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Sheets(ws.Name).Select

        lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        Set rowRange = ws.Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Sort Key1:=rowRange, Order1:=XLAscending, Header:=XLYes

    Next ws
    ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: (1) Remove the `_` from the `Set rowRange` line.  The `_` is used as a line continuation character in VBA. (2) Split that line into two - one line doing the `Set` and the next line doing the `Sort` (using `rowRange.Sort`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

rowRange is a range, according to your declaration. You should first set it:

```
Set rowRange = ws.Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
```

and then, in the next line, sort.

```
rowRange.Sort Key1:=rowRange, Order1:=XLAscending, Header:=XLYes
```

Also, selecting of the worksheet is not necessary. If it was, ws.select is more then enough.

Comment: of course, just copied Smock's code without checking. My fault.